# How to select and COPY (Ctrl + C) the text of jLabels?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Given a jLabel in NetBeans with some text on it, when it the usser runs the app, how is it possible to make that text selectable and copyable by the user?

Comment: Do you mean in the UI builder, or in the application when the application is running?

Comment: Please post your code. Or explain better than where you want to do it, in the Netbeans UI, programmatically

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Once the app is runing. @A L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given a jLabel in NetBeans with some text on it, how is it possible to make that text selectable and copyable by the user?

Netbeans has nothing to do with this.

A JLabel is designed to display text. If does not have any functionality that will allow you to select the text or copy the text.

Keyboard commands only work on components with focus. A JLabel by default won't get focus.

Instead you could use a JTextField. You would need to alter some properties on the text field to make it look like a JLabel:

1. set the Border null
2. set opaque to false
3. set editable to false.

Even this may not work because the component will need focus in order for the Ctrl+C to be handled by the text field. So you may also need to invoke:

4. set focusable to true (after setting editable to false)

Even if Ctrl+C doesn't work you should be able to use the mouse.

Comment: Nice point, but I was trying to avoid the use of jtextField since those does not allow HTML formatting. Isn't there any other solution?

Comment: *textField since those does not allow HTML formatting.* - well that was not part of the requirement in the question was it? Think about the context of the suggestion given. Text components do support copy. The suggestion showed how to make a text component look like a label. If you don't like the JTextField, then what other text component does support HTML? You have 3 other components to choose from. Use the component that meets your requirements.

Comment: I am sorry, but this question should be marked  **duplicated** as Gabriel H stated above. The anwser provided by @Arend was pretty useful.